# For some reason, paint() is being called twice

Tags: java, applet, paint

This is my code:

```
public class Circles extends JApplet{
public void paint(Graphics g)      {          

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

    int position = rand.nextInt(200);

    System.out.println(position);            
   }
}
```

and the output was:

> 199
>
> 152

What's happening is after it prints out the "position" variable, it jumps back and starts again. I cant figure out why it does this.

Comment: It only prints once for _me_ when launching this program.

Comment: When is it printing twice for you? When you first launch the program?

Comment: Don't mix console based input with graphic interfaces, especially in the applet environment. Paint may be called the RepaintManager for any number of reasons, any number of times, this is an inappropriate use of paint

Comment: yes when I launch it, it gives out two numbers. Did you change anything when you ran it?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I know I shouldn't do that, I was just testing why I kept getting the wrong output when I was trying to draw circles for my assignment. Originally I had to "draw 50 circles at random positions with random diameters" But I kept getting the wrong amount of circles due to paint() being refreshed.

Comment: Take a look at. [Performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Creating a GUI With Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: That's probably because you weren't calling super.paint(g)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As MadProgrammer noted, you're trying to paint to a JApplet, which not only doesn't have a paint method, but is a top-level container like a JFrame and a JDialog. You don't want to paint to a top-level container. Put it in a JPanel or some lower level container that allows you to override the paintComponent method.

You do not want to put that in your paint method. Also, use the `paintComponent` method if you're using Swing (which you are, it's the ones with the J at the front of their names).

And make sure you call the original parent method of paintComponent with `super.paintComponent(g);` as your first line in the `paintComponent` method.

So it will look like:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //anything else you want goes here
    //don't get in the habit of creating Objects in here
    //and don't do anything that's not event-driven
}
```

Don't put anything other than painting stuff in your overridden paintComponent method. You should never put user input into it and avoid creating objects because not only is there probably a better way to do it, creating objects can take a lot of time which will be terrible for a method that's called in quick, repeated succession.

You don't have control over when your application is repainted. The `paintComponent/paint` methods are called continuously, and your design should be based around that.

Design your GUI to be event-driven, not sequential.

Comment: Don't forget, JApplet doesn't have a paintComponent method ;)

Comment: Oh man, now I'm more confused than ever. I tried drawing a simple circle that way but it didn't work. Then I tried it again using a for loop which didn't work either.

Comment: What did you put in your code? Edit it into your code if you can. I made a small little example for you where a circle gets drawn every time a button is clicked: http://pastebin.com/EwYZVnAf  check that out and tell me if you understand it a little better!